# How to get attached file by URL from local CouchBase-Lite?

Tags: couchdb, couchbase

We are trying to get an image file that has been attached to a Doc in a local CouchBase-Lite.

I'd like to be able to get this files by using the same URL syntax used for the CouchDB Remote server. (Just point to local server instead of remote)(http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#Attachments)

I can seem to find how to do this.
 Anyone know how? Thanks

Comment: Are you using Couchbase Lite-iOS or Couchbase Lite-Android? And you are looking for an URL to an image file stored in local DB(cblite), am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are actually asking about Couchbase-Lite (aka TouchDB, ie. the embedded iOS/Android SDK) then you should look here http://couchbase.github.io/couchbase-lite-ios/docs/html/interfaceCBLAttachment.html (or the Android equivalent if that's what you're working on).

I'm not sure why you're also asking about URL syntax if that's what you're doing, so I'm not sure that is what you're doing, but hey - there's your answer.  You can clarify if you were talking about something else.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer because I'm also looking for a solution to this. I am using CBL iOS and i want to get the local database URL to be able to get info from it.

This is what i have so far :

```
string[] paths = NSSearchPath.GetDirectories(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomain.User);
var request = new NSMutableUrlRequest();
request.Url = new NSUrl(paths[0], false);
request.HttpMethod = "GET";
var data = NSUrlConnection.SendSynchronousRequest(request, out response, out error);
if(error != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error in SendRequest=" + error.LocalizedDescription);
    throw new HttpRequestException(error);
}
```

And this prints out in the console : Error in SendRequest=The requested URL was not found on this server.

the URL is something like this :

file:///Users/ME/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.0/Applications/ABFDF-ADBAFB-SFGNAFAF/Documents/users/user